# C# to VB.net convertion error

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, error-handling

I am trying to use MIDI.NET in Visual Basic 2010 while it is written in C#. So I got the tip to convert it using an online converter since these languages are quitte similair to eachother.
The one problem I have is this line

```
inputDevice.NoteOn += new InputDevice.NoteOnHandler(NoteOn);
```

converted to vb.net it looks like this

```
InputDevice.NoteOn += New InputDevice.NoteOnHandler(NoteOn)
```

which gives me 2 errors.

1. 'Public Event NoteOn(msg As NoteOnMessage)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.  C:\Users\Den Houting\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\MIDI\Form1.vb 14  9   MIDI
2. Error    3   Delegate 'Midi.InputDevice.NoteOnHandler' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.  C:\Users\Den Houting\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\MIDI\Form1.vb 14  82  MIDI

When trying to do something like `RaiseEvent NoteOn` it tells me NoteOn isn't an event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax in VB.NET uses `AddHandler` to register the event

```
AddHandler InputDevice.NoteOn, AddressOf NoteOn
```

More on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: This is the right answer but in C# the operator += works for multicast delegates. Can you post a multicast delegate example in vb.net to get a full answer that match C# features? I can do it myself but I don't wanna repeat a correct answer.

Comment: @jlvaquero Go for it as I won't have time to do it quickly and can't do it from the top of my head.